# SASL severity 2 password verification failed

Tags: ubuntu, php-fpm, sasl, php-memcached

I have PHP Memcached running I have binary turned on (both memcached process & php) I am using Memcached::setSaslAuthData Using Ubuntu 14.04

SASL is enabled I just continually get:

mech: ``PLAIN'' with 46 bytes of data SASL (severity 2): Password verification failed sasl result code: -20 Unknown sasl response: -20

From what I understand this means SASL_NO_USR I have created the user in sasldb2 The user running the memcached process has read/write permissions to /etc/sasldb2 When I run the sudo sasldblistusers2 -f /etc/sasldb2 command the user is listed.

Question: How do I properly troubleshoot/fix the password verification failure above.

Update:

I had to download and install memcached from source using the —enable-sasl configure flag.